# Can't promote PostgreSQL warm standby server to start serving data

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.4, centos-7

Scenario:

- Two CentOS 7 machines, with ips 10.0.2.15 and 10.0.2.4
- Both running PostgreSQL 9.4.6. First one (10.0.2.15) as master, and second one (10.0.2.4) as slave, not listening for clients (just mirroring data via WAL shipping).

**Problem: I can make log shipping work (so, slave receives WAL files), but I cannot promote slave to accept connections.**

What I did:

**In master:**

Created user for replication from slave:

```
psql -c “CREATE USER rep REPLICATION LOGIN CONNECTION LIMIT 1 ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ‘replication’;”
```

Allowed slave to connect as replication user, with this line in pg_hba.conf:

```
host    replication    rep    10.0.2.4/32    md5
```

postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = archive
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -av %p postgres@10.0.2.4:/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/archive/%f —exclude=postmaster.pid'
max_wal_senders = 3 # Using just 1, but anyway...
```

**In slave:**

Deleted data repository

```
rm -fr /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
```

Made a base backup

```
pg_basebackup -h 10.0.2.15 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data -U rep -v -P
```

(I enter the password, and the base backup is properly made: new data directory now)

Added recovery.conf to new data directory just created. With this info:

```
standby_mode='off'
restore_command='pg_standby /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/archive %f %p %r'
```

Directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/archive exists in the slave, and it's writable for postgres.

So, the master-slave process is working. WAL files are being sent via rsync. But if I just try this in slave:

```
pg_ctrl promote
```

**I get the message "server promoting", but nothing happens. And no new messages in the log. Still can't connect to the server via psql. No incoming connections accepted.**

**What should I do to promote the slave to serve data as a normal server?** I'm talking about a **high availability scenario**, with a warm standby server starting to act as a normal server, allowing clients to connect.

I know I can change parameters in the slave to make it run as *normal* server, but I just think there should be a quick way to put my slave server to work. I thought it was just pg_ctl promote. But probably, I'm missing something.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, made it work by using the **-R flag in pg_basebackup**. This flag automatically generates the recovery.conf file with the right parameters

From the [official doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgbasebackup.html):

```
-R
--write-recovery-conf
Write a minimal recovery.conf in the output directory (or into the base archive file when using tar format) to ease setting up a standby server.
```

Comment: Just a comment: the recovery.conf generated includes a primary_conninfo parameter. So, this means streaming replication is enabled. If I don't want streaming replication, I should use restore_command instead.

Comment: The restore_command can be like this: restore_command = ‘cp /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/archive/%f %p’